# Dynamic updating of upper limits of constraints when a matrix is updated

Tags: matrix, dynamic

I have a system represented by a matrix `mFull`:

```
Clear[n, m, mFull, G, a, A1, A2, A3, A4, constraintsFull, reducedSystem];
SeedRandom[13];
n = 4;
m = 6;

(* Full system *)
mFull = {{0, a1[1, 2], a1[1, 3], a1[1, 4]}, {a2[2, 1], 0, a2[2, 3], 
    a2[2, 4]}, {a3[3, 1], a3[3, 2], 0, a3[3, 4]}, {a4[4, 1], a4[4, 2],
     a4[4, 3], 0}};

(* constraints for individual elements in "mFull" *)
constraintsFull = Table[{
    0 <= a1[1, j] <= 1,
    0 <= a2[2, j] <= 1,
    0 <= a3[3, j] <= 1,
    0 <= a4[4, j] <= 1}, {j, 1, n}];  (* for all j *)
```

Then, I set upper limits for each type of `a`, for example for the upper limit for `a1` is equal to the sum of the elements in the `1st` row of `mFull`. These upper limits are calculated by:

```
(* define Upper Limits for "mFull" *)
upperLimitFull = {
   {A1Full = Total[Ta[![enter image description here][1]][1]ble[a1[1, j], {j, 1, n}] /. a1[1, 1] -> 0]},
   {A2Full = Total[Table[a2[2, j], {j, 1, n}] /. a2[2, 2] -> 0]},
   {A3Full = Total[Table[a3[3, j], {j, 1, n}] /. a3[3, 3] -> 0]},
   {A4Full = Total[Table[a4[4, j], {j, 1, n}] /. a4[4, 4] -> 0]}
   };
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Then I update the original system `mFull` by introducing a digraph `G`. Each time I change `G`, the constraints and upper limits of the `reducedSystem` should be updated accordingly.

```
(* For the reduced system *)
G = RandomGraph[{n, m}, DirectedEdges -> True];
reducedSystem = AdjacencyMatrix[G]*mFull;

constraintsReduced = {
   0 <= a1[1, 4] <= 1,
   0 <= a2[2, 1] <= 1,
   0 <= a2[2, 3] <= 1,
   0 <= a3[3, 2] <= 1,
   0 <= a4[4, 1] <= 1,
   0 <= a4[4, 3] <= 1
    };

(* define Upper Limits for "reducedSystem" *)
upperLimitReduced = {
   {A1reduced = reducedSystem[[1]] // Total},
   {A2reduced = reducedSystem[[2]] // Total},
   {A3reduced = reducedSystem[[3]] // Total},
   {A4reduced = reducedSystem[[4]] // Total}
   };
```

The updated system has a different set of constraints with different upper limits, which are displayed below in RED color.

[image]

As one can see, upper limits of the `mFull` system are different from those of the `reducedSystem`.

My goal is to have an efficient `code` that does the entire process of updating automatically. Every time I update the system, the `constraints set` and `upper limits` as described above should be updated.

Comment: are the red numbers the number of non-zero elements in the corresponding row?

Comment: @kglr: For this example, the answer is `YES` because each element in the respective row has an upper bound 1 in the `constraints set`, for example, `0<= a1[1,3] <=1` etc. In general, however, the answer is `NO` because the individual elements in a row could have been bounded by any integer `K`. In such case, the RED number for each row would be `K* number of nonzero elements`.

Comment: @kglr: I could not find any typo in the `constraintsReduced`. When you look at `AdjG` matrix, the positions of  `1`s in this matrix should be in the `constraintsReduced` set. This is the case in the formulation. I hope nothing escapes from my attention.

Comment: I see. I evaluated without copying `SeedRandom[13]`  i got different system:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClearAll[feasibleQ]
feasibleQ[k_] := List /@ Thread[(Total /@ #) <= (k Count[#, Except[0]] & /@ #)] &;

feasibleQ[1] @ mFull // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  \text{a1}(1,2)+\text{a1}(1,3)+\text{a1}(1,4)\leq 3 \\
>  \text{a2}(2,1)+\text{a2}(2,3)+\text{a2}(2,4)\leq 3 \\
>  \text{a3}(3,1)+\text{a3}(3,2)+\text{a3}(3,4)\leq 3 \\
>  \text{a4}(4,1)+\text{a4}(4,2)+\text{a4}(4,3)\leq 3 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
feasibleQ[k] @ reducedSystem // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  \text{a1}(1,4)\leq k \\
>  \text{a2}(2,1)+\text{a2}(2,3)\leq 2 k \\
>  \text{a3}(3,2)\leq k \\
>  \text{a4}(4,1)+\text{a4}(4,3)\leq 2 k \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
SeedRandom[13]
graphs =Table[RandomGraph[{n, m}, DirectedEdges -> True], {10}];
Grid[Flatten /@ Partition[{#, MatrixForm @ 
  feasibleQ[k][mFull AdjacencyMatrix @ #]} & /@ graphs, 2], 
 Dividers -> {{{True, False}}, All}]
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfect...Thanks a lot for all you have done.

Comment: @Tugrul, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.